# Checking if Username and Password are correct

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

As my code is right now, I always get the `echo "Username/Password incorrect.";` whether or not the username/password match or not. My question is, What did I do wrong in the code below for the php to always echo "Username/Password incorrect"

```
<?php
require 'privstuff/dbinfo.php';

$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed. Please send an email to owner@othertxt.com regarding this problem.";
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username=? and password=?")) {

    $db_pw = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $db_pw);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {

        echo "Logged in.";
    }else{
        echo "Username/Password incorrect.";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close(); 

?>
```

**Update** I've changed `if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)` to `if ($stmt->num_rows)`. Still doesn't work though
**UPDATE 2** I've realized the issue is me using  `password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` I didn't realize that the hash gives different strings every time. I'm not understanding on how to use password_verify

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Did you try with `$stmt->num_rows` instead of `$stmt->affected_rows`?

Comment: Yes I have @CharlotteDunois

Comment: What do you get if you dump $stmt `var_dump($stmt);`?

Comment: As you fetch the user information why not check that directly? Also, you cannot rely on the 'affected row counts' and 'row count' values for 'select' statements as some of the drivers don't update them until you start to fetch them. None of them update with the 'total' count as they would have to read all the returned rows to provide an accurate count.

Comment: Super stupid question I'm not sure on what you mean by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was not supposed to use password_hash again. I didn't realize that using password_hash gave different results. I then changed it to use password_verify.

```
<?php
require 'privstuff/dbinfo.php';


$username = $_POST["username"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `accounts` WHERE username = ?")) {

    /* Bind parameters: s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $username);

    /* Execute it */
    $stmt -> execute();

    /* Bind results */
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);

    /* Fetch the value */
    $stmt -> fetch();

    /* Close statement */
    $stmt -> close();
}


if(password_verify($password1, $result))
{
    echo("Hello");
}else{
    echo("No-Go");
}

$mysqli->close(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of [`mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) says:

> This function only works with queries which update a table. In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) instead.

You also need to call [`mysqli_stmt_store_results()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) first, to buffer the results.

```
$stmt->store_results();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just looked that up. For `SELECT` affected_rows works just like num_rows.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) says: This function only works with queries which update a table. In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use mysqli_stmt_num_rows() instead.

Comment: Then I saw an outdated mysql(i) documentation page. Thanks for the update.

Comment: It might works as an undocumented feature, but `store_results()` is still needed first.

Comment: "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::store_results() in <b>/othertxt.com/login.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />"

Line 21 is `$stmt->store_results();`

Comment: the OP should be using PDO anyway, not `mysqli`.

Comment: @Alnitak: I prefer PDO also, but will MySQLi not work?

Comment: @Alnitak Why? mysql is deprecated, mysqli is not.

Comment: @Alnitak Do you have a way of fixing this error in PDO?

Comment: PDO is even worse for this. Its `numRows` method is only guaranteed to work for modification statements, it might or might not work for `SELECT`. The best solution in PDO is to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` in your query.